# Selecting texts from an image using html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wonder how can we select texts over an image using html5. I found a commercial application. There is only one basic image on source code ([image](https://api.groupdocs.com/v2.0/doc/7557dad4b80fa61d/files/054b452e8ffaa826f336d556ca0e960e887be4e09e38dd28b4891f7ac9bcd890/pages/0/images/852x?quality=&use_pdf=True&expires=253402300800000&v=2&signature=HJMFM1zVVdIAO1Q7I%2B8SFF3S%2B0s)) but when you use image viewer app you can reach all of the text of image and you can highlight it. [live demo](http://groupdocs.com/apps/annotation/live-demo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do it yourself you need to implement a font/letter-detecting alogrithm in HTML5. You would use it on a pixel-data-array of a HTML-Canvas-Element. And once you detected the letters you would make them words and position them at the correct position over the Picture, but with a transparent color.

But such a thing is really complex. Does this answer help you?

Comment: Do you know an open source application that converts image to selectable HTML5 code.  Thank you  for answer.